# Java Date constructor unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, date, locale

I am just providing a value of 2160000000 (which is 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 25 - just 25 days) to Date's class constructor. I expected to see that here will be 1970-01-26 00:00:00, but what I received is 1970-01-26 03:00:00 (additional three hours)! I haven't found any points that this constructor also depend on JVM locale settings, and all I have found is info about leap second. But leap second is NOT three hours in bounds of the single month of the same year. But anyway I've changed default locale (to US one. I'm located in Europe) in a test method just for experiment, but nothing changed.

I have received this just by this (what I have explained just ok earlier ya know):
    `Date date = new Date(1000* 60 * 60 * 24 * 25);`
(this is just for example purposes). I saw actual values just using debugger, that's all:

[image]

Comment: Explain what you did to get `1970-01-26 03:00:00` from the `Date` object.

Comment: Yeah, some code example would be nice

Comment: We interested not how you've created `Date` object, but how you output it or you saw it in IDE debug or what?

Comment: I get `Sun Dec 07 16:57:12 AEST 1969` - my guess is you have TimeZone issue

Comment: Your screenshot confirms TimeZone issue, sice date ends with +0300

Comment: Ugh, okay, now i know what it does stand for. Strange, because i haven't found this dependency in Date's class javadoc... Thanks, @Piro

Comment: Also `LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).plus((1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L) * 25L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)` might provide a better overall solution

Comment: Yes, seems to be so. Thanks, @MadProgrammer !

Comment: The troublesome `Date` and `Calendar` classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. No reason to be using them in 2018.

Comment: @BasilBourque, but here are projects that aren't started at 2018 but still need support. That doesn't touch the original question anyway

Comment: When inter-operating with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert back and forth using new methods added to the old classes. If using Java 6 or 7, much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. As I said, there is no reason to be using `Date` class in 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the `Date` you expected, a `Date` of 1970-01-26 00:00:00 **UTC**. This point in time is equivalent to 1970-01-26 03:00:00 at UTC offset +03:00.

In your debugger you are looking into the private fields of the `Date` object. These are not documented for clients (that’s the point), so don’t expect any particular values.

I believe that you would find `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 25)` less confusing. Or still better, `Instant.EPOCH.plus(Duration.ofDays(25))`. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is much nicer to work with. If you do need a `Date` for a legacy API that you don’t want to change just now, I recommend getting an `Instant` first and then using `Date.from(yourInstant)` so you minimize your use of (and dependence on) the outdated and confusing `Date` class.

Finally, changing locale makes no difference. While time zone and UTC offset are closely connected (to a degree where some think it’s the same :-) locale hasn’t really got anything to do with them. Instead the locale deals with the language and cultural norms of a group of users — it doesn’t even need to be tied to a geographical location.

**Link:** [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)

Comment: Thanks, this answer is close to perfection!

Answer (score 2):

Do you think the hour difference you're seeing is being equal to your home country's time zone (GMT+3) is a coincidence? I think not.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = dateFormat.parse("/*TimeToParse*/");
```

This would definitely help.

Edit: If you check the zoneOffset and ZoneInfo values in your debug screenshot, you'll understand better.

Comment: I know how to fix that. I just want an answer of what is going on with this constructor, cuz I haven't found any info about dependencies on JVM's locale settings. Only about leap seconds, which is doesn't quite satisfy my question

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 2_160_000_000L )
```

## java.time

[The Answer by Acar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292628/642706) is likely correct: You are confused by the unfortunate design of `Date::toString` to dynamically apply your JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string. One of *many* reasons to never use the troublesome `Date` class, now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

To represent a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 2_160_000_000L ) ;
```

If your real intent is to represent 25 whole days as a span of time unattached to the timeline, use a `Period`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ) ;

Period p = Period.ofDays( 25 ) ;
LocalDate later = today.plus( p ) ;
```

Comment: My real intent was just to get what the heck is going on here. But thanks, your answer is quite useful!